Prepare API testing in Spring
I would like to prepare API set of tests for my base controller. Here is a part of him.
public class BaseController {
    .....
    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public
    ResponseEntity<ResponseDto> read(@RequestParam Long id) {
        return abstractService.read(id);
    }
}

However in this case I do not want to have main configuration SpringBootClass.
Testing with this approach
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class AbstractControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    @Test
    public void testRead() throws Exception {
        long userId = 1L;
        ResultActions result = mockMvc.perform(get("/api/users/{id}", userId));
        // Assert
        result.andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}

Requires to provide SpringBootConfiguration class is there any solutions or mocking to fullfill this requirement or test this API ?

Usually you would just use @WebMvcTest(controllers = BaseController.class) which will instantiate only the controller specified. With @WebMvcTest you don't need @SpringBootTest
